# Python: In List, adding counts of tuples with same string name together

Tags: list, python-3.5

In my list L below, how can I add "alex" together, so 19+ 12=21 count for alex.

For mike, how can I add to produce single (mike, 30) tuple from these 2 tuples

```
('mike / 213880_at', 15),
('mike / 210393_at', 15),
```

Same for marko: how to get (marko, 24) from the tuples below inside the list:

```
('marko / 229481_at', 12),
('marko / 1553115_at', 12),

L = [
    ('alex / 222696_at', 19),
    ('mike / 213880_at', 15),
    ('mike / 210393_at', 15),
    ('NOTUM / 228649_at', 13),
    ('marko / 229481_at', 12),
    ('marko / 1553115_at', 12),
    ('alex / 224176_s_at', 12),
    ('pocke / 227812_at', 11),
    ('locke / A_23_P111995', 10),
    ('nicko / 225016_at', 10),
    ('kolya / A_23_P122216', 10),
    ('raj / 211518_s_at', 9),
    ('dave / 240211_at', 8)
]
```

Comment: What's with the `/` and following digits/codes?

Comment: @Alexander  I am working on biological data. unfortunately, that's how the data is given.

name of gene and then its probe number.

"alex / 222696_at'

I don't care about probe number, only gene names, and its frequency in my genetic datasets.

Comment: So to simplify this problem, first introduce a step to process the input data into a separated name and probe number.

Comment: Yes @Alexander, I will use more pre-processing. str.split() is very handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
L = [
    ('alex / 222696_at', 19),
    ('mike / 213880_at', 15),
    ('mike / 210393_at', 15),
    ('NOTUM / 228649_at', 13),
    ('marko / 229481_at', 12),
    ('marko / 1553115_at', 12),
    ('alex / 224176_s_at', 12),
    ('pocke / 227812_at', 11),
    ('locke / A_23_P111995', 10),
    ('nicko / 225016_at', 10),
    ('kolya / A_23_P122216', 10),
    ('raj / 211518_s_at', 9),
    ('dave / 240211_at', 8)
]
new = {}
for name, number in L:
    val = name.split(' / ')[0]
    if val in new:
        new[val] += number
    else:
        new[val]= number
print(new)
```

Output:

```
{'alex': 31, 'mike': 30, 'NOTUM': 13, 'marko': 24, 'pocke': 11, 'locke': 10, 'nicko': 10, 'kolya': 10, 'raj': 9, 'dave': 8}
```

If you wanted back in a tuple:

```
#add this
new = tuple([(x, new[x]) for x in new])
```

Comment: thank you @abccd 
do you know dict.most_common() function which can be applied for this tuple "new"?

Comment: I don't quite get what do you mean? `dict` doesn't have a most_common attitude, a `collection.Counter` has one for finding the most common value

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to retain list order and have O(1) look-ups.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def add_pairs(sequence):
    container = OrderedDict()
    for tag, value in sequence:
        key = tag.split()[0]
        container[key] = container.get(key, 0) + value
    return container
```

**Example:**

```
>>> L = [
('alex / 222696_at', 19),
('mike / 213880_at', 15),
('mike / 210393_at', 15),
('NOTUM / 228649_at', 13),
('marko / 229481_at', 12),
('marko / 1553115_at', 12),
('alex / 224176_s_at', 12),
('pocke / 227812_at', 11),
('locke / A_23_P111995', 10),
('nicko / 225016_at', 10),
('kolya / A_23_P122216', 10),
('raj / 211518_s_at', 9),
('dave / 240211_at', 8)
]
>>> add_pairs(L)
OrderedDict([('alex', 31), ('mike', 30), ('NOTUM', 13), ('marko', 24), ('pocke', 11), ('locke', 10), ('nicko', 10), ('kolya', 10), ('raj', 9), ('dave', 8)])
```